# CURL post to HTTP post format

Tags: http, curl, https

can anyone help me to convert this CURL to HTTP Post
curl -s -X POST --upload-file resources/project.sql http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/pt/upload_resources

i tried following syntax for above curl cmd using below http  but it doesnt worked out.

POST --upload-file resources/project.sql /v1/pt/upload_resources HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Tiny;


__END__

Created from curl command line
curl -s -X POST --upload-file resources/project.sql http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/pt/upload_resources
```